# Python debugging - Spyder - Pause during execution

Tags: python, debugging, spyder, pause

My python code is taking longer than expected to run. I am using spyder 5.2 and python 3.9. Is there a way to pause execution arbitrarily to check the line that is currently running and examine the variable explorer? I would like the variable explorer to show local variables within a function if a function is running at the time.

After checking the code, I would like to restart the code from the point it had stopped.

Notice that I am not referring to setting breakpoints before the code is run. Rather, what I want is to be able to pause the code at will, during execution.

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This functionality is already available in our `master` branch, which means it'll be part of Spyder 6, to be released in 2023. We added a new Debugger pane which has a button to interrupt the current computation in order to enter the debugger and check why it's taking so long.

To resume execution afterwards, you'd need to write in the `IPdb` prompt the command `!continue`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can do this in PyCharm. However, it would be wise to check out the documentation on the `pdb`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Usually as in other languages we use `print()` to debug. However, this doesn't work in every situation.